# Plot an array along with multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe where I'm trying to plot two of its columns for which I do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y1', ax = ax, label = 'y1', marker='.')
df.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y2', ax = ax, label = 'y2', marker='.')
```

The problem happens when I'm trying two plot a third variable (`y3`) along with those pandas columns. `y3` calculated doing the following:

```
z = np.polyfit(df['x'].values, df['y2'].values, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)
y3 = f(df['y2'].values)
```

I have used the following two approached to add this to my previous plot:

```
ax.plot(x = df['x'].values, y = y3, label = 'estimated', marker = '^')
```

this does not throw any exception but I can not see the new line added to my plot so basically generates the same plot. I have also tried:

```
plt.plot(x = df['x'].values, y = y3, label = 'estimated', marker = '^', ax = ax)
```

which throws:

```
TypeError: inner() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'
```

How would I add that third line to my plot using values stored in `y3` which by the way is a numpy array?

Comment: Try `ax.plot(df['x'].values, y3, label = 'estimated', marker = '^')` by removing `x=` and `y=`

Comment: For matplotlib's  `plot`, x and y are *positional* arguments. For pandas `plot` they are *optional* named (keyword-) arguments.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: This could be important information to the readers. Do you mind if I post both comments as an answer?

Comment: If this is the first question where someone stumbles upon this problem, you should provide an answer. If it isn't you can mark as duplicate.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for the response. I will post as an answer for the moment. If someone comes up with a duplicate, I would be simply delete my answer and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks for the comment, actually that worked just fine. Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the explanation. I did not know about x and y being positional arguments for matplotlib's `plot`. I think it would be useful to have these comments posted as an answer.

Comment: @ahajib: Glad to know that. I posted the discussion as an answer for the sake of future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two plots, you use your DataFrame `df` to directly plot the columns using `df.plot()` where the `x` and `y` are required as *keyword (optional)* arguments (i.e., works without `x=` and `y=` as well) ([official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)). So using `x=...` and `y=...` works for `df.plot()`.

However, in your third plot command, you are using the axis instance `ax` for plotting using `ax.plot()` where you are just using the DataFrame values as arguments. `ax.plot()` accepts x and y values as *positional* arguments as clarified by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest).

So to answer your problem, you need to use

```
ax.plot(df['x'].values, y3, label = 'estimated', marker = '^')
```

by removing `x=` and `y=` from your plot command.

The same way, following would work too

```
plt.plot(df['x'].values, y3, label = 'estimated', marker = '^')
```

where `plt` refers to the current axis object.